# Can not resolve the symbol 'Transactional'

Tags: java, spring-boot

have this code. I'm studying the springboot framework

```
package com.cursojava.curso.dao;

import com.cursojava.curso.models.Usuario;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class DaoUsuarioImplementacion implements UsuarioDao{

     @Override
     public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
       return null;
    }
}
```

And the IDE send me an error in Transactional. When I hover on it, it says "Create anotation". No problem I said, I go more options>add Maven dependency, but no matter how I search it only appears "TransactionalTestExecutionListener".
I tried invalidating caches, deleting the .idea directory and still appears this problem.
I'm using the community edition of IntelliJ

I tried invalidating caches, searching in the dependencies, deleting the .idea directory, restarting the IDE, restarting the PC.

Comment: You're missing the import for `Transactional` (`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`). And if you can't find that, then you don't have the `spring-tx` dependency on your classpath, which means you don't have the relevant dependency or Spring Boot starter specified in your Maven pom.xml.

Comment: Are you using gradle or maven? If so: please [edit] the post and add your `build.gradel` / `pom.xml`.